# WPF Design Data

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to insert some design data in a control by temporarily setting datacontext in xml. The contents are defined by the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel;
using AITReportEditor.Infrastructure.Models;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace AITReportEditor.Infrastructure.Models
{
    public class ComponentItem : NotificationObject
    {

        //Constructor for expression Blend sample data
        public ComponentItem() { }

        public ComponentItem(AITReportEditor.Infrastructure.Models.Component copyItem)
        {
            this.PartData = new PartDataItem(copyItem.PartData);
            this.ObjectId = copyItem.ObjectId;


            Files = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();
            foreach (File existItm in copyItem.Files)
            {
                FileItem fileItem = new FileItem(existItm);
                Files.Add(fileItem);
            }

            SpareParts = new ObservableCollection<SparepartItem>();
            foreach (Sparepart existItm in copyItem.Spareparts)
            {
                SparepartItem sparepartItem = new SparepartItem(existItm);
                SpareParts.Add(sparepartItem);
            }
        }



        private ObservableCollection<FileItem> _files;
        public ObservableCollection<FileItem> Files
        {
            get { return _files; }
            set
            {
                _files = value;
            }

        }

        private ObservableCollection<SparepartItem> spareparts;
        public ObservableCollection<SparepartItem> SpareParts
        {
            get { return spareparts; }
            set
            {
                spareparts = value;
            }

        }



        private string _objectid;
        public string ObjectId
        {
            get { return _objectid; }
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(_objectid))
                {
                    _objectid = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ObjectId);
                }

            }
        }

        private PartDataItem _partdata;
        public PartDataItem PartData
        {
            get { return _partdata; }
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(_partdata))
                {
                    _partdata = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.PartData);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace AITReportEditor.Infrastructure.Models
{
    public class PartDataItem : NotificationObject
    {

        public PartDataItem() { }



        public PartDataItem(InspectionObject copyItem)
        {

            this.Name = copyItem.Name;
            this.Note = copyItem.Note;
            this.Status = copyItem.Status;

        }


        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(_name))
                {
                    _name = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Name);
                }

            }

        }


        private string _note;
        public string Note
        {
            get { return _note; }
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(_note))
                {
                    _note = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Note);
                }

            }

        }

        private int _status;
        public int Status
        {
            get { return _status; }
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(_status))
                {
                    _status = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Status);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

In xaml i define datacontext with

```
xmlns:inf="clr-namespace:AITReportEditor.Infrastructure.Models;assembly=AITReportEditor.Infrastructure"

<UserControl.DataContext>
        <inf:ComponentItem>
            <inf:ComponentItem.ObjectId>1212</inf:ComponentItem.ObjectId>
            <inf:ComponentItem.PartData>
                <inf:ComponentItem.PartData.Name>klas</inf:ComponentItem.PartData.Name>
            </inf:ComponentItem.PartData>



        </inf:ComponentItem>

    </UserControl.DataContext>
```

The ObjectId works fine, but I can't seem to define the partdata. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

[UPDATE] Made some changes

Instead of defining sampledata insiede usercontrol datacontext I'm setting design data in the external file and changing xaml to

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" d:DataContext="{d:DesignDataSource=./../../SampleData/SampleData.xaml}">
```

in the control and defining sample data in seperate file

```
<m:ComponentItem xmlns:m="clr-namespace:AITReportEditor.Infrastructure.Models;assembly=AITReportEditor.Infrastructure"
                 ObjectId="12321">
    <m:ComponentItem.PartData Name="Klas" />

</m:ComponentItem>
```

But I'm still getting "Cannot set property on element..." when I try to add PartData to sample file.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THink i solved it, seems to be all in the syntax for typed classes probaly obscurely hidden away in yet another book i haven't read. To solve it i made a simpler projet with 3 classes Person, Invoice and ContactInfo

```
 public class Person
    {
        public Person()
        { }


        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Invoice> Invoices{get; set;}

        public ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; set; }

    }

     public class Invoice
        {
            public int Amount { get; set; }
    }

 public class ContactInfo
    {

        public ContactInfo()
        {

        }
        public string Adress { get; set; }
    }
```

The syntax for the design data that works is then

```
<m:Person xmlns:m="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2" Name="Klas">
    <m:Person.Invoices>
        <m:Invoice Amount="12" />
        <m:Invoice Amount="12" />
        <m:Invoice Amount="12" />
    </m:Person.Invoices>
    <m:Person.ContactInfo>
        <m:ContactInfo Adress="Lena"></m:ContactInfo>
    </m:Person.ContactInfo>
</m:Person>
```

Notice that if you want to use the list invoices you have to add

```
private List<Invoice> _invoices = new List<Invoice>();
        public List<Invoice> Invoices
        {
            get { return _invoices; }
            set { _invoices = value; }
        }
```

in the class.

Hope this could be of value to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is PartData, being a reference type, has no instance to set the Name property on.  The string, being a value type, is automatically created. Try:

```
private PartDataItem _partdata = new PartDataItem();
```

I hope you realize that setting design time data should be done by writing dependency properties on your control, as that will allow you to set design time data on your control through attributes in the xaml.  DataContext is meant for setting dynamic data (can be used at design time, but not really the intent).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer did not work though, same problem. Visaual Studio complains with "Cannot set properties on ...". I have made some changes and defined a external file and using "{d:DesignData Source=SampleData.xaml}" instead of datacontext. I will make changes to explain in the the question.